# Simulated (dry) quicksand

Tags: production, effects

I've been watching the original Lost in Space series (1965). In at least a couple of episodes, a character would fall or get pulled into "quicksand". In each case, the material is obviously dry - upon escape, the character's clothes are clean and dry. For example: in the cold open of the season 1 episode "A Change of Space", Smith falls into a pit of the stuff and completely disappears under its surface - it has a fluid-like behavior, but after his escape, only a few grains remain stuck to his costume, which remains dry. There doesn't appear to be any visual effect here; Smith's (or his stunt double's) momentary disappearance under the surface of this stuff appears to be entirely a practical effect. To get technical, it looks like some sort of light granular material that has a very shallow [angle of repose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose)

My question is: what did they use for the sand/dust or whatever, to achieve the effect?

Comment: I'd like to see a clip, if anybody can find one.

Comment: @Tetsujin https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x553n5m

Answer (score 2):

My first guess was [Vermiculite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermiculite) - the stuff they put in the bottom of the burner on "real flame" gas fires - I'm trying to track down some good confirmation of that...

[Google Books - Eye on Science Fiction: 20 Interviews with Classic SF and Horror Filmmakers](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jFkWaFYqzuQC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=vermiculite+movie+quicksand&source=bl&ots=WopPRPpjV-&sig=fHBZUwWqPq-mAjwYgaG4EUrsxN8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpkqqGjrbeAhXGbMAKHfC0DlkQ6AEwCXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=vermiculite%20movie%20quicksand&f=false)

> [image]

[Answers.com - What can I use to make a quicksand scene for a film or a location?](http://arts.answers.com/Q/What_can_I_use_to_make_a_quicksand_scene_for_a_film_or_a_location) includes other possibilities, but doesn't differentiate between wet & dry...

> Most common is sawdust and oil. Vermiculite and Fuller's Earth makes a quicksand almost safe enough to eat. Ground cork is one of the best ways, as it leaves the actors relatively clean when they're pulled out.

Comment: Chopped cork pieces might also be an option *sans* water - https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=e16x9LJW6mwC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=making+quicksand+special+effect+movie&source=bl&ots=zqkC-Eo34n&sig=PGRR2fusQY_exzTqL7ViHVdTQR0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYt4e2j7beAhUMC8AKHb2JAjAQ6AEwFHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=making%20quicksand%20special%20effect%20movie&f=false

Comment: @Paulie_D - yup, mentioned in the 2nd link. I can find all sorts of stuff on wet quicksand, but dry is taking some tracking down

Comment: Exfoliated vermiculite definitely has the required properties - its incredibly light (used as a light and absorbent packing material when transporting chemicals) and you could disappear under enough of it.  It does tend to stick with static to clothing though.

Comment: Also possible would be a fluidized sand bed as seen here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My4RA5I0FKs